# Application Request Routing: Why some sites return HTTP 404 some don't?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, load-balancing, web-farm-framework

I want to add a load balancer to an existing asp.net project using *Application Request Routing*. So I made myself familiar with the concepts and created a local **test-setup**:

- IIS locally running on Windows 10:

  - Installed Application Request Routing 3.0 with Windows Platform Installer
  - Created server farm with following servers:

    1. `<test-server-name>.de` (Microsoft 2012 R2 Server: contains the asp.net project)
    2. `www.google.com` (just to see if load balancing and url rewriting works because I don't have two test servers available)

**URL-Rewriting rule:** 
[image: url rewrite rule]

After typing `localhost` multiple times in any browser, I can see that load balancing (weighted round robin) is working fine. It's alternating between 1. and 2. website.

The problem I'm facing is a **404 Error** on both websites.
[image]

**I already tried the following:**

- **Installing and enabling *Failed Request Tracing Rules*** (on local IIS): URL Rewriting is working properly i think.
  Failed Request Log for `www.google.com`: [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LuBpcjAFaEnAKIAjlS4IlQNxw3zrYyeX/view?usp=sharing), unzip and open `xml` in e.g. IE for better view
- **Create Server Farm without automatic creation of URL Rewrite rules**[image]

  (selecting *No* and create own URL Rewrite rule)
- **Change *"Managed Pipeline Mode"*-setting of Applcation Pool** from *Integrated* to *Classic*
- **Healthcheck on other Websites**[image]    I have absolutly no clue why it's working on Git-websites and why facebook is returning a 400 error code.
- **Enabling/disabling proxy** (IIS-Manager -> Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings...)

I don't know what i could do next, so I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found here: https://forums.iis.net/t/1238739.aspx?Why+some+sites+return+HTTP+404+some+don+t+

Some websites simply don't support `localhost` as hostname, which is why `localhost` can't be found (error 404) e.g. on `google.com`

Detailed answer if link above is not working in future:

> That is not an effective test.
>
> What you are doing is sending the hostname of your request to the third party servers. Like Google.
>
> So if your request is say http://example.com you are sending this to say www.google.com and the Google servers will likely reject this as you can see
>
> Web server admins generally don't let themselves receive traffic from domain thet do not host.
>
> If you sent a request to my servers IP with mysite.com I too would likely reject it. (Things get complex if you have wildcard sites and you allow all traffic through)
>
> But simply showing that 404 page from Google means tour request hit there server so that implies ARR is working.
>
> If you really wanted to test it this way have a local host file with www.google.com resolving to your servers IP. Set up a site with www.google.com as the hostheader and then you should see the correct info hitting Google. But there is no accounting for what 3rd party admins do on their side.